# Use value of parent element attribute in binding, with attribute not being part of the model

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have few knockout attributes that are not associated with model. Rather i am assigning rank to every list element(incremental list +1). Now i want to use this rank1 element in child tags.

But i realize that i can't do it directly since its not coming from Model (example IsPremium below).

So I am finding closest element that has this rank1 attribute to find its value. I feel this is not optimized way since it will look up everytime.

Can i somehow bind this attribute to child elements as well?

Below is the code.

```
<script type="text/html" id="listingTemp">
   <li data-bind='attr: {rank1 : $.getRank(IsPremium), isPremium :       IsPremium}>
      <div class="stock-detail">
      ..few other nested elements
      <a class="slideShow" data-bind="attr: { isPremium : IsPremium} onclick="$.triggerSearchListingsTracking($(this).attr('isPremium '),$(this).closest('.listingContent').attr('rank1')
```

Comment: why not to create a function in your VM that takes `index, IsPremium` and return rank? then use it in whatever place you want!

Comment: sorry i have edit the problem, not passing $index() in getRank anymore.

getRank is defined in separate js file:
getRank = function(isPremium)
{
  if(isPremium)
  { indexPremium++;}
  else{ indexNonPremium++;}

Comment: Can i use this rank returned in child tags below somehow. Since if i would call this again and again, it would increment the gloabl parameter multiple times which i obviously don't want.

Comment: @sahil `IsPremium` aren't you getting from vm ? if you want `rank` attribute on `li's` child elements what don't you decorate the child elements with `attr:{'rank';isPremium}` .

Comment: I am getting isPremium from model. rank1 is something i am creating using global variables. Now i want to access this rank1 in child element (anchor tag above).

I have choice to do it by accessing rank1 from closest element or somehow bind rank1 directly here which would be more optimized.

I want to know how can i bind it directly with anchor tag?

Comment: @sahil you are mixing knockout and jquery pretty much , tough you can achieve everything using ko . use ko `click` , `.bind` for function call in vm etc

Comment: @sahil try this `data-bind="attr: { isPremium : IsPremium}"  onclick="$.triggerSearchListingsTracking($(this).attr('isPremium '),$.getRank($(this).attr('isPremium'))))"` let us know

Comment: This would increment global variables everytime it is called which is not intended. It just be just called once and somehow i should be able to reuse the returned value in all the child elements.

Comment: alrighty @sahil `closest` is the way to go here http://jsfiddle.net/MUBHF/10/

Comment: i have already done that (refer to the last line). I wanted to check if there is any other better way.

Comment: there isn't any , as far imho , tough you can achieve the same in simplest for terms if your'e willing to make `getRank` as viewModel function as first commenter pointed out. @sahil can you do that ?

Comment: Please, show all the relevant code: when do you create the elements? How do you set the attribute? There are ways to modify data bound to elements, so that you could include an isPremium observable in your model, and populate it will you calculate it. Later on you can use it in allyour bindings.